# I have moved my package.json file one folder up in react project and now `npm start` is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, react-hooks

my current folder structure is

```
   -- project folder
         |-- package.json
         |-- react-project
                  |-- src folder
                  |-- public folder
```

My node version is 18

Comment: you must run `npm start` where your `package.json` is. If there is something in the `package.json` pointing to a fixed folder structure them you must update it

Answer (score 2):

In order for `npm start` to work, you have to run the command from the same directory as your `package.json`.

`node_modules`, `package-lock.json`, and `package.json` should always be at the root of the project as a good practice.

If you move these files/folders it can disrupt the pathing of them.

For example, inside `package.json` at the top you will a line somewhat like: `"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js"`. If you move `node_modules` or `package.json`, then this will no longer work. It would need to be changed to something like, `"./node_modules"` or `"../node_modules"`

If there is a specific reason you need to move this folder, then you will have to do some reconfiguring to ensure the pathing is correct.

Comment: Yes there is a reason. The issue here is when I run `npm start`, the  terminal throws message can't find public folder. In react index.html is startup file which reside inside public folder.

So what changes I will have to do in package.json ?
currently my start script is  `react-scripts start`